# Can Calabash be used as test tool only having ipa file?

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, calabash, calabash-ios

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm planning to develop a UI test automation for an iOS application.

The problem is that I don't have access to the source code but only the finished ipa file of the app. Therefore I cannot add Calabash.framework to the app.
Is there a possibility to write UI tests with Calabash or do I need the source code of the app to add Calabash.framework before creating the ipa file?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Calabash on an ipa.  Compile-time linking is no longer strictly required.  See https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/pull/750 - this is a work in progress.  I am no longer working on the Calabash project, but I can provide some guidance.